Image Upload Issue with Theme Rain Core Plugin in WordPress
I'm encountering an issue with image uploads on my WordPress website while using the Theme Rain Core plugin. I've identified the section of code where modifications can be made, and I've attempted to change the code type as a beginner, particularly in the section related to media insertion.
Here's a summary of the problem:
I'm able to change the code type and insert media successfully.
However, when I upload an image and try to display it on the site, instead of the image appearing, a numerical value is displayed, which I presume is referencing the image.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
    switch ( $field['type'] ) {

            case 'text':
                $html .= '<input type="text" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '" value="' . wp_kses_post( $meta ) . '">';
                break;

            case 'textarea':
                $html .= '<textarea id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '" rows="5">' . wp_kses_post( $meta ) . '</textarea>';
                break;

            case 'url':
                $html .= '<div class="themerain-meta-url__wrap">';
                $html .= '<i class="themerain-meta-url__icon"></i>';
                $html .= '<input type="url" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '" value="' . esc_url( $meta ) . '">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                break;

            case 'checkbox':
                $html .= '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '"' . ( $meta ? ' checked' : '' ) . '>';
                break;

            case 'toggle':
                $html .= '<div class="themerain-toggle' . ( $meta ? ' is-checked' : '' ) . '">';
                $html .= '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '"' . ( $meta ? ' checked' : '' ) . '>';
                $html .= '<div class="themerain-toggle__track"></div><div class="themerain-toggle__slider"></div>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                break;

            case 'select':
                $html .= '<select id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '">';
                foreach( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ) {
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"' . ( $meta === $value ? ' selected' : '' ) . '>' . esc_html( $label ) . '</option>';
                }
                $html .= '</select>';
                break;

            case 'color':
                $html .= '<input type="text" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '" value="' . sanitize_hex_color( $meta ) . '">';
                break;

            case 'range':
                $range = isset( $field['range'] ) ? ' min="' . $field['range'][0] . '" max="' . $field['range'][1] . '" step="' . $field['range'][2] . '"' : '';

                $html .= '<input type="range" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $id . '" value="' . esc_attr( $meta ) . '"' . $range . '>';
                $html .= '<span class="themerain-meta-range__value">' . esc_attr( $meta ) . '</span>';
                break;

            case 'group':
                foreach ( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ) {
                    $html .= '<label class="button' . ( $value === $meta ? ' button-primary' : '' ) . '">';
                    $html .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $id . '" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"' . ( $value === $meta ? ' checked' : '' ) . '>';
                    $html .= $label . '</label> ';
                }
                break;

            case 'media':
                if ( isset( $field['media'] ) || isset( $field['media_type'] ) ) {
                    $media     = $meta ? '<div></div>' : '';
                    $data_type = 'video/mp4';
                    $btn_text  = 'Upload video';
                } else {
                    $media     = $meta ? '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( esc_attr( $meta ) ) . '">' : '';
                    $data_type = 'image';
                    $btn_text  = 'Upload image';
                }


Welcome! If this is a problem with your theme, I would suggest asking their support team for help. Any changes made to that theme will be lost if the theme/plugin is updated.
